Calculating higher-order correlation functions of the Ising model
I'm trying to compute the correlation functions $<s_1...s_n>$ of specific n-spin subsets as a function of the temperature in systems with up to $N=256^2$ spins. These will be used to compute other quantities. I have used two approaches:

Monte Carlo simulation: The spin product for each subset is calculated at each step and then averaged. This estimates the correlation functions for any system size.
Graph enumeration: The Ising model is represented as an undirected graph and the correlation functions can be calculated exactly by enumerating all possible graphs with certain constrains. This becomes intractable for large systems.

The number of subsets that I'm interested in is in the order of ~$10^5$. Monte Carlo simulation cannot be run for long enough since ~$10^5$ quantities are measured at each step, which is computationally expensive. I was wondering if there are other methods for better calculating/estimating higher-order correlation functions for the 2D Ising model.

Do you have to calculate the quantities at every step? It's common to wait for the system to equilibrate before calculating expensive quantities, or, in non-equilibrium contexts, only do measurements every M steps.

Measurements are made after equilibration and only the correlation functions are calculated at every step.
